# XPath to select a node with an attribute value and a child node value

Tags: xpath

Background -  Visual Studio 2010, C#,  .Net Framework 4.0 application

I have a web site that receives XML and based off that XML, I need to trigger additional processing to occur.

I receive the following XML  (I have shortened it down to a minimal XML)

```
<Event xmlns="http://www.mysite.com"  et='a'>
<audit>
    <cb>foo</cb>
</audit>
</Event>
```

I have been using the following XPath to see if the document matches for additional processing.. (checking to see if I get any "Event" nodes back).

```
        //std:Event[@et='a']
```

Where I have struggled is that I need to find all Event nodes where the et attribute is "a" and the audit/cb node had a value of 'foo'

This is where I am struggling... Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you *Have* to use XPath? I know there are many people who swear by it, but I'd use LINQ to XML myself. In particular, it makes namespace handling much simpler.

Comment: the xPath gets setup in a "route" definition, so there are different xPaths for different processing.   switching over to  LINQ to XML would be interesting, but would take time to update and convert everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of the C# and .NET but in pure XPath syntax I believe it would be:

```
//Event[@et='a']/audit[cb='foo']/..
```

Check out Xpath syntax at: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: This finds `audit` nodes, not `Event` nodes.

Comment: Thanks... this helped me out a lot.. I have a lot to learn about xPath syntax.  I had to modify a little bit to include the name space  //std:Event[@et='a']/std:audit[std:cb='foo']

Comment: I tried to vote up, but my reputation is not high enough.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not a .NET user myself but try this:

```
//Event[@et='a' and audit/cb = 'foo']
```